# Cloud Functions as API

Tags: android, retrofit2, google-cloud-functions

I want to use HTTP Cloud functions as API.I used Retrofit as REST Client and sent the POST request(I used HTTP Cloud function URL as API endpoint).Functions read the parameters sent as POST parameters and processed them, I want to pass something from the function to the client back as a response.How can I do it?
Here is my cloud functions code:

```
exports.Add = functions.https.onRequest((req,res)=>{
//var testPublicKey = sk_test_N63fpbFHY2pN7XAllv9D5qjw
var stripe = require("stripe")("stripe_key");

console.log("Token:"+req.body.Token)
console.log("Amount:"+req.body.Amount)

var tokenToCharge = req.body.Token;
const amountToCharge = req.body.Amount;
var authID = req.body.AuthID;
const databaseRef = admin.firestore();
const payer = databaseRef.collection('deyaPayUsers').doc(authID).collection('Wallet').doc(authID);
 const balance = payer.Usd
 stripe.charges.create({
amount : amountToCharge,
currency : "usd",
description : "charge created",
source : tokenToCharge,
}, function(err, charge) {
if(charge.status === "succeeded"){
var trans = databaseRef.runTransaction(t=>{
 return t.get(payer)
    .then(doc=>{
     var updatedBalance = doc.data().Usd + parseInt(charge.amount);
     t.update(payer,{Usd : updatedBalance});
    });//return close
 }).then(result=>{
 console.log('Transaction success!');
 }).catch(err=>{
 console.log('Transaction Failure:',err);
 });
 }
});
});
```

Here is my REST client

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                               .baseUrl(" https://us-central1-deyapay-
                               192704.cloudfunctions.net/tokenAmt/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
                        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
                        executeForm(token1,a,UID);
   private void executeForm(String Token,Integer Amt,String UID){
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(" https://us-central1-deyapay-192704.cloudfunctions.net/Add/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        Retrofit retrofit =  builder.build();

        APIService apiservice=retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        Call<PostData> call=apiservice.savePost(Token,Amt,UID);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<PostData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PostData> call, Response<PostData> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(Stripe.this, (CharSequence) response.body(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PostData> call, Throwable t) {
             Toast.makeText(Stripe.this,"Failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

My POJO class

```
public class PostData {

    @SerializedName("Token")
    @Expose
    private String token;
    @SerializedName("Amount")
    @Expose
    private Integer amount;
    @SerializedName("AuthID")
    @Expose
    private String authID;

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public Integer getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(Integer amt) {
        this.amount = amt;
    }

    public String getAuthID(){return authID;}

    public void setAuthID(String authID){
        this.authID = authID;
    }

}
```

Comment: display APIService class code

Answer (score -1):

Similar to Express.js the response has `.status()` and `.send()`

simply add `res.status(200).send('stringified JSON')` near your `console.log('Transaction success!')`
You can leave out the status but it's a good idea to have it. Maybe even send other statuscodes whenever your application fails?

Comment: How do you receive it in client side

Comment: Assuming your code works it will be part your response.body() in your callback onResponse

Comment: I want to return a string from my backend, so I want to retrieve response.body() as a string but when I tried it, the type of response.body() must be PoatData which is the name of my POJO class.

Comment: I'm not really able to assist you with the android/java part of your problem.

Comment: what is stringified JSON